# How can we read an R variable from JS chunk?

Tags: javascript, r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Hello guys any idea how to read an R variable from JS chunk ?

I tried to save the R variable on a txt file then read it from the JS chunk but I could not figure out how because it was not working

Comment: Are you using Shiny?  That's basically what it is for.

Comment: No, I am using flexdashboard.
Can you please explain more @user2554330

Comment: This page:  https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/ describes the process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I dont need to create server/client, I prefer to keep it simple if possible

 it is just creating an R chunk defining a variable then after it create another JS chunk and try to read it in the same Rmarkdown

Comment: You can include static R values in the text:  see https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html.  So just put one into the Javascript that you are writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how complicated you want things to be.

The simplest solution is what I said in the comment:  just use inline R code to put values directly into the Javascript as part of your text.  This doesn't work if the Javascript is in a chunk, only if it is in raw `<script></script>` form.  For example,

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
msg <- "This doesn't work."
```

```{javascript}
alert("`r msg`")
```

```{r}
msg <- "This works:  this is a message from R!"
```

<script>
alert("`r msg`")
</script>
````

More complicated versions would involve writing an `htmlwidget`, which is a bit tricky but allows arbitrary Javascript code to be executed when you print an R object, or going to Shiny, if you want the R code to respond to the user viewing the web page.

Comment: That worked like a charm ! thanks men. I was putting my code in a JS chunk not between <script></script>.